# next js refetches on shallow routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

well i have this next js app and i want it to redirect to `/` when the user clickes the logo in the navbar. But i don't want it to run `getStaticProps` every time it goes back to `/`. because i'm fetching a lot of data `getStaticProps` and it considerably slows down the redirect every time i want to go back to `/`.
i am using next's `Link` component on the navbar image like this.

```
<Link href='/' shallow={true}>
  <Image src={`${someImageUrl}`} width={100} height={100} />
</Link>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. In production, `getStaticProps` runs once on the server at build time, it won't run whenever a page is requested. In development, `getStaticProps` will be called on every request but when using shallow routing it shouldn't run when the navigation occurs.

Comment: yeah turns out that behavior only occurs on the dev server. this won't be an issue on the production build